# PHP - block request from other domain

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have some links like this

```
http://www.domain1.com/files/domain1.com/files/def.jpg

http://super.domain1.com/files/super.domain1.com/files/abc.jpg

http://www.other1.com/files/other1.com/files/uhj.jpg
```

These websites are hosted in the same hosting and sharing files folder. We separate them by using a sub folder named like domain name of website. However, file which belong to domain1.com:

```
http://www.domain1.com/files/domain1.com/files/def.jpg
```

can be reach with url

```
http://www.other1.com/files/domain1.com/files/def.jpg
```

How to prevent this?

Comment: You need to write a rewrite rule that check referrer then allow/deny to access actual files.

Comment: I _think_ this is more of a configuration/layout question and should therefore be handled at http://serverfault.com (not sure though...)

Comment: So actually you're sharing the files folder, but don't want to share it. See the solution there? Only put files you actually want to share in the shared folder, and keep the other files (ie. your def.jpg) in a subfolder that is not shared between the domains.

Answer (score 0):

Get configure for each domain separately vhost to domain folder.

Example of vhost config i post below.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName www.domain1.com

        DocumentRoot /home/domains/files/super.domain1.com/

        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/domains/files/super.domain1.com/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName domain1.com

        DocumentRoot /home/domains/files/super.domain1.com/

        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/domains/files/super.domain1.com/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```